# MySQL deadlock caused by concurrent INSERT and SELECT

Tags: mysql, deadlock

- MySQL version: 5.6
- Storage engine: InnoDB

The deadlock occurred when two tasks tried to `select` and then `insert` the same table. The procedure looks like:

```
          Task_1       Task_2
          ------      ------
Phase 1 | SELECT      SELECT
Phase 2 | INSERT      INSERT

SELECT count(id) from mytbl where name = 'someValue' and timestampdiff(hour, ts, now()) < 1;
INSERT mytbl (id, name, ts) values ('newId', 'anotherValue', now());
```

The deadlock log is as following (with some details truncated):

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
151225  8:22:17
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 0 746402, ACTIVE 0 sec, process no 4690, OS thread id 140411390486272 inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 1172 lock struct(s), heap size 112624, 32914 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 3909, query id 31751474 10.20.36.38 mydb update
INSERT INTO mytbl -- truncated
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 5044 n bits 88 index `PRIMARY` of table `MYDB`.`mytbl` trx id 0 746402 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 0 746449, ACTIVE 0 sec, process no 4690, OS thread id 140411389953792 inserting, thread declared inside InnoDB 500
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
1172 lock struct(s), heap size 112624, 32914 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 3906, query id 31751477 10.20.36.38 mydb update
INSERT INTO mytbl  -- truncated
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 5044 n bits 88 index `PRIMARY` of table `MYDB`.`MYTBL` trx id 0 746449 lock mode S
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 5044 n bits 88 index `PRIMARY` of table `MYDB`.`MYTBL` trx id 0 746449 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

---

### Questions

1. According to MySQL manual, the simple `SELECT` statement uses snapshot read which requires no *S lock*. The `INSERT` statement requires *X lock* on the single row to be inserted. Then why `Task_2` held an *S lock* and resulted in deadlock?

---

### Edit

The result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` is as following:

```
| task_content | CREATE TABLE `mytbl` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`ts` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Comment: You can change the isolation level of your transactions to serializable. But usually the best course of action is to avoid `selects` in transactions if possible.

Comment: Some really interesting information about deadlocks here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-deadlocks.html

Comment: Is the sources of transactions same?

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam No, the two transactions were invoked by two different sessions generated by IBATIS API.

Comment: Can you test it at same location? what happend then?

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam Would you please specify "test at same location"?

Comment: Run statements one by one at one system and see what time it takes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your current isolation level is `repeatable read` or stronger, to be able to repeat the same result for `select count(id) ...` within a transaction MySQL has to lock the whole primary key (or a part of another key used by `WHERE` condition). Then you modify the key by inserting a new value. But the concurrent transactions modify the state of the key, which has already been seen. Both can start with the same state of the key, and then wait until the other is finished with no changes, so that it would apply its own changes.

Comment: In InnoDB, isn't the `SELECT` supposed to be consistent read (i.e. snapshot read) with no shared lock?

Answer (score 11):

The article [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/08/28/differences-between-read-committed-and-repeatable-read-transaction-isolation-levels/) gives a exhaustive explanation about the locks and isolation levels.

Thank @newtover for giving the clue about isolation level. My summary of the article and the answer to my own question is as following:

The default isolation level in InnoDB is *Repeatable Read*, which would lock the index (not locking the data table) until **the end of transaction**.

In my circumstance, the only index is `PRIMARY`, which was useless in my `SELECT` query (can be verified by `explain select...`). As a result, **all** entries in the `PRIMARY` index were locked. When `TXN_2` waited for an *X lock* on a certain entry, the entry was locked by an *S lock* retained by `TXN_1`. Similarly, `TXN_1` waited for an *X lock* on another entry but the entry was also locked by *S lock* retained by itself. A ["one S two X"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-lock-modes.html) deadlock occurred.

By contrast, after I created an index `name` on the column `name`, the index `name` would be used in the `SELECT` statement (can be verified by `explain select ...`), so the locks would be issued on the index `name` instead of `PRIMARY`. More importantly, the `SELECT` statement would only issue *S lock* on the entry equals to `someValue` instead of all entries of index `name`. Besides, the *IX lock* and *X lock* required by `INSERT` would be issued on the index `PRIMARY`. Conflicts between *S lock* and *IX lock*, *X lock* would be solved.

The index on column `name` did not only speed up the query but more importantly prevented locking all entries of the index.

Comment: Sometimes the solution is so simple like that. I've created a index on the column who I'm using to do the where and all is fine now. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

> where name = 'someValue' and timestampdiff(hour, ts, now()) < 1;

That is rather inefficient.  Let's clean that up to speed things up, to decrease the likelihood of a deadlock.

`timestampdiff(hour, ts, now()) < 1` hides any index with `ts`; let's rewrite it to

```
ts < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
```

Yours truncated in unexpected ways; mine says "ts older than 1 hour ago", which I suspect you wanted.

Now we can index `ts` to good effect.  But let's carry it further by using a "composite" index:

```
INDEX(name, ts)
```

This will efficiently use both parts of the `WHERE` clause for locating the row(s).

You say `COUNT(id)` -- this implies that you need to avoid `NULLs` in `id`.  Perhaps that is not a concern, and you could say simply `COUNT(*)`.

Those should make the `SELECT` faster.  Now let's figure out why that `SELECT` and `INSERT` have anything to do with each other.  Are they in the same transaction?  Or do you have autocommit turned OFF, but forgot to say `COMMIT`?  Please show us the entire transaction, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: According to the deadlock log, the `SELECT` and `INSERT` were in the same transaction, which is exactly my question. The `autocommit` option was `ON`.

Comment: The indexing suggestion is to decrease "32914 row lock(s)" (among other things).

Comment: Is 'someValue' the same in both transactions?

Comment: I have other questions that are best answered by `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: I appended the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` in the question. I had created an index on column `name` which has decreased the number of row locks to 1. The `someValue` were different in different transactions.

Comment: OK, now continue with the rewrite of the `WHERE` and the addition of the composite index.

Answer (score 0):

Write your every query in **BEGIN** and **END** transaction. I hope it will not happened.

More : [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html)

Answer (score 0):

The written part of query seems to be correct & definitely its NOT source of your problem. I guess your tasks are executing interleave and at the begining, each task starts a transaction. You didn't say anything about how to execute these tasks and what the primary key value is when you execute each of them?
You may want to change your primary key field to AUTO_INCREMENT or make sure that the primary key which is used by your tasks are really unique.
If it didn't help, an alternative (but not suggested) solution would be protecting your procedure calling code at upper level by a mutext.